# Ajustar gráfico automaticamente

Tags: php, javascript, html, iframe

Fiz a implementação de dois gráficos no meu site.

Quando vejo o resultado final tudo parece perfeito, o problema e quando faço a visualização pelo meu telemóvel, apenas aparece parte do gráfico e não o total.

Tentei mudar as definições para 100% de altura e largura mas ao visualizar o gráfico aparece com barras laterais para visualizar o resto.

Como posso resolver isto?

```
<iframe frameborder="0" width="1150px" height="320px" src="http://xxx.pt/mares/index.php?country=Portugal&state=Regiao de Lisboa&city=Lisboa&dias=3&longitude=-9.139&latitude=38.722&hidemenu=1"></iframe>
```

Comment: Voce ta setando a width do seu iframe como 1150, ele sempre vai cortar no mobile desse jeito. Porque nao seta o elemento "pai" do iframe com 100% de width e ele tb?

Comment: Ao alterar wight e height para 100% ele automaticamente cria barras laterais para visualizar o resto do gráfico.